# How do I set CSS style with jquery based on the page loaded?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I´m pretty new with Jquery, so I´m not really sure what functions I should be using for my case.

I have a list of links, like so:

```
<ul class="topmenu">
           <li class="selected"><a href='index.html'>Hem</a></li>
           <li class=""><a href='services.html'>Tjänster </a></li>
           <li class=""><a href='about.html'>Om oss </a></li>
           <li class=""><a href='vaccancies.html'>Lediga jobb </a></li>
           <li class=""><a href='contact.html'>Kontakta oss </a></li>
</ul>
```

This is part of my footer, and I´m including this footer in all my pages using jquery load:

```
$('#footer_include').load('footer.html');
```

Now, my issue is that I want to be able to dynamically set the class "selected" to my list items, based on what page the user is currently on. So if the user is on vaccancies.html, I want the class for that list item to be set to "selected". So I´m guessing something like

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     ...
             $(this).addClass('selected');
     ...

});
```

But as you can see, my code is incomplete... Can someone help me finish it? I guess I might need to add IDs to the individual list items aswell?

Cheers!

Comment: Just a slightly off-topic comment that in this case it'd be better to use a server-side scripting language to include the footer into each page if you have one available.

Comment: I believe you're using Javascript in a wrong way and have not understood its point. Its seems really wrong to use it to initialize your page (what about people who deactivate JS?) ; everything you're trying to do with JS here should be done server-side thanks to a scripting language (PHP for instance).

Comment: OK, I could agree that PHP would be better for the include. But how would set the CSS class dynamically using PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add custom data attributes

```
<ul class="topmenu">
    <li data-pathname="/index.html" class="selected"><a href='index.html'>Hem</a></li>
    <li data-pathname="/services.html" class=""><a href='services.html'>Tjänster </a></li>
    <li data-pathname="/about.html" class=""><a href='about.html'>Om oss </a></li>
    <li data-pathname="/vaccancies.html" class=""><a href='vaccancies.html'>Lediga jobb </a></li>
    <li data-pathname="/contact.html" class=""><a href='contact.html'>Kontakta oss </a></li>
</ul>
```

JQuery:

```
$('li[data-pathname="' + window.location.pathname + '"]').addClass('selected');
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/CstXK/

If you wanted to use PHP to set the class, you could do this:

```
<?php

  $selected['index']      = ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/index.html')      ? $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] : '';
  $selected['services']   = ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/services.html')   ? $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] : '';
  $selected['about']      = ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/about.html')      ? $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] : '';
  $selected['vaccancies'] = ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/vaccancies.html') ? $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] : '';
  $selected['contact']    = ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/contact.html')    ? $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] : '';

echo <<<HTML
<ul class="topmenu">
    <li class="{$selected['index']}"><a href='index.html'>Hem</a></li>
    <li class="{$selected['services']}"><a href='services.html'>Tjänster </a></li>
    <li class="{$selected['about']}"><a href='about.html'>Om oss </a></li>
    <li class="{$selected['vaccancies']}"><a href='vaccancies.html'>Lediga jobb </a></li>
    <li class="{$selected['contact']}"><a href='contact.html'>Kontakta oss </a></li>
</ul>
HTML;
```

Of course that PHP could be cleaned up with an array iteration and a substr, etc., but you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks alot for giving me code for both jQuery and php! I guess I´ll go with PHP for this one!

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#footer_include').load('footer.html', function(){
   var p = document.location.toString().split('/');
   var str = p[p.length-1];
   var loc = str.split('?')[0];
   $('#topmenu a[href="' + loc '"]').addClass('selected');
});
```

I hope this could help

Answer (score 0):

You can reference your code for setting selected page by adding your js code to each page, as this is the easiest way to do.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        // Remove selected from last visited page.
        $(".aclass").removeClass("selected");

        // Set current selected page.
        $(".aclass[href$='index.html']").addClass("selected")
});
```

Where "aclass" is a class added for each "`<a class='aclass' />`" element.

Answer (score 0):

check the anchor's href value against the current location

http://jsfiddle.net/k3rRN/

```
$('.topmenu a').each(function() {
    var $that = $(this);

    // check if the anchor href matches the current pathname 
    // then add selected to parent
    if (window.location.pathname.indexOf($that.attr('href')) > -1) {
        $that.parent().addClass('selected');
    }
});
```

Answer (score -2):

You will definitely need to add ids to the list items so that you can know which one you are marking as selected.

As far as identifying the page you are on, one way to do so is to put an id on the HTML or BODY element that indicates the page. You can then look for an element in the page that has a given id and set the selected list element accordingly.

Comment: For what do you need ID's? See also the answer of @Senad Meškin.

Comment: @feeela - Yes, I see that now. However, without resorting to parsing out the URL (perhaps it is more complicated?), then putting a token identifier into the page is much faster.

Comment: Depends on your definition of "much faster", but I wouldn't care for a couple of milliseconds.